# bit representation of a double number

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I did this program, which functions as expected, to know the bit representation of a float:

```
float x1=-675.78125;
int *pint1;
pint1=(int *)&x1;


for(int i=0;i<8*sizeof(float);i++)
{

if(*pint1&1)
{
    cout<<1;
    }
else
    cout<<0;
    *pint1>>=1;

}
```

But it doesn't work for a double:

```
double x=-675.78125;
int *pint;
pint=(int *)&x;

for(int i=0;i<8*sizeof(double);i++)
{

    if(*pint&1)
    {
        cout<<1;
        }
    else
        cout<<0;
        *pint>>=1;

    }
```

Could you explain me why this is so? how would you do it? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `double` is a different size than `int` on your machine. And you can also start by fixing the indentation.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Note that both programs violate the strict aliasing rules since you try to access the double as an int.

Comment: StackOverflow Rule of Thumb #3: If the post says "it's working as expected", it is in fact just broken.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "doesn't work" means that when I use the first program to get the bit representation of the number the result is 11000100001010001111001000000000 (of course in the other way around, which agrees with the teoretical result). trying to do the same with double it produces only 0's as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your first program seems to work and your second doesn't is that for your particular hardware, the size of a float is the same as int, while an int doesn't have enough room for all the bits in a `double`.

But you're already violating the strict aliasing rules, so if you really want to print the bits of a floating point type the right way to do it is to cast to `unsigned char*` and then iterate over each bit of the char while incrementing the pointer over each byte of the underlying floating point type. Also note that on big-vs-little endian the results of your program may vary.

Comment: @MarkB I'm a little confused. A pointer points to the first position of the address, accordingly. And a pointer only needs room to save the address of the variable that it is pointing to. So, I don't get the part "an int pointer doesn't have enogh room for all the bits in a double".

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: Not an *int pointer*. An *int* doesn't have enough room for a double. When you cast and dereference, you're treating the bits stored at `x`'s address as an int. Print `sizeof(float)`, `sizeof(double)`, and `sizeof(int)` and compare them.

Comment: @MarkB Thank so much to all of you. I'm just a novice and I'm tryint to understand averything from the c foundations up, which seems to be a lot of work but I really feel good when I come to understand it. In this case I finally understood the point that the '<<' operator only moves as much positions as *pint allows before it gets only 0's, which seems to be at least sizeof(int), then I followed the suggestion of making iterations exactly before it happens. Again, thank you so much.