# C++ Double to Binary Representation (Reinterpret Cast)

Tags: c++, pointers, char, endianness, reinterpret-cast

I've recently decided to create a program that'll allow me to print out the exact bit pattern of an instance of *any* type in C++. I'm starting with the primitive built-in types. I've ran into an issue with printing the binary representation of a `double` type.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void toBinary(ostream& o, char a)
{
    const size_t size = sizeof(a) * 8;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        bool b = a & (1UL << i);
        o << b;
    }
}

void toBinary(ostream& o, double d)
{
    const size_t size = sizeof(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d) + i;
        toBinary(o, *c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    cout << a << " as binary: "; 
    toBinary(cout, static_cast<char>(a));
    cout << "\n";

    double d = 5;
    cout << d << " as double binary: ";
    toBinary(cout, d);
    cout << "\n";
}
```

My output is the following:
5 as binary: 00000101

5 as double binary: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010001000000

However, I know that 5 as a floating point representation is: 
01000000 00010100 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Maybe I'm not understanding something here, but doesn't the `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d) + i` line I've written allow me to treat a `double*` as a `char*` so that adding `i` to it will advance the pointer by `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(double)`. (Which is what I want here)? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: little vs big endian.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328993/bit-representation-of-a-double-number

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you. That seems to explain it. My program seems to be printing it in big-endian format whereas the floating point representation I'm looking for is printed in little endian.
@ πάντα ῥεῖ, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you interpret a numeric type as a "byte sequence" you are exposed to the machine endianess: some platform store the most significant byte first, other do the reverse.

Just observe your number, in 8-bit groups, reading it from the last group towards the first and you get exactly what you expect.

Note that the same problem also happens with integers: 5 (in 32 bit) is

```
00000101-00000000-00000000-00000000
```

and not

```
00000000-00000000-00000000-00000101
```

as you wold expect.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to familiarize myself more with machine endianess.