# Get exact bit representation of a double, in C++

Tags: c++, hash, types, hashtable, bit

Let us say that we have a double, say, x = 4.3241;

Quite simply, I would like to know, how in C++, can one simply retrieve an int for *each* bit in the representation of a number?

I have seen other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328993/bit-representation-of-a-double-number) and read the page on [bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328993/bit-representation-of-a-double-number), but I'm afraid I still do not understand how to retrieve those bits.

So, for example, I would like the input to be `x = 4.53`, and if the bit representation was `10010101`, then I would like 8 ints, each one representing each `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```
double doubleValue = ...whatever...;
uint8_t *bytePointer = (uint8_t *)&doubleValue;

for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(double); index++)
{
    uint8_t byte = bytePointer[index];

    for(int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
    {
        printf("%d", byte&1);
        byte >>= 1;
    }
}
```

... will print the bits out, ordered from least significant to most significant within bytes and reading the bytes from first to last. Depending on your machine architecture that means the bytes may or may not be in order of significance. Intel is strictly little endian so you should get all bits from least significant to most; most CPUs use the same endianness for floating point numbers as for integers but even that's not guaranteed.

Just allocate an array and store the bits instead of printing them.

(an assumption made: that there are eight bits in a byte; not technically guaranteed in C but fairly reliable on any hardware you're likely to encounter nowadays)

Comment: This will print the bytes from the most significative one to the least one by one from the least significative bit to the most. I'm not sure this order makes any sense.

Comment: What order _does_ make sense? There's a reason endianness issues exist. The whole representation choice is quite arbitrary. The question here is about _accessing_ the bits, and although I think other orders would be more fortunate, it's really up to the OP to decide on these follow-up choices.

Comment: Yes, and I believe it should be mentioned since OP might be oblivious of that concept.

Answer (score 8):

This is extremely architecture-dependent. After gathering the following information

1. The [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your target architecture
2. The floating point representation (e.g. [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point))
3. The size of your `double` type

you should be able to get the bit representation you're searching for. An example tested on a x86_64 system

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
  double v = 72.4;

  // Boilerplate to circumvent the fact bitwise operators can't be applied to double
  union {
    double value;
    char   array[sizeof(double)];
  };

  value = v;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT; ++i) {
    int relativeToByte = i % CHAR_BIT;
    bool isBitSet = (array[sizeof(double) - 1 - i / CHAR_BIT] & 
       (1 << (CHAR_BIT - relativeToByte - 1))) == (1 << (CHAR_BIT - relativeToByte - 1));
    std::cout << (isBitSet ? "1" : "0");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c08de5b6bef34feb)</kbd>

The output is

```
0100000001010010000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

which, split into `sign`, `exponent` and `significand` (or mantissa), is

```
0 10000000101 (1.)0010000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

[image]
(Image taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))

Anyway you're required to know how your target representation works, otherwise these numbers will pretty much be useless to you.

Since your question is unclear whether you want those integers to be in the order that makes sense with regard to the internal representation of your number of simply dump out the bytes at that address as you encounter them, I'm adding another easier method to just dump out every byte at that address (and showing another way of dealing with bit operators and `double`)

```
double v = 72.4;

uint8_t *array = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&v);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i) {
  uint8_t byte = array[i];
  for (int bit = CHAR_BIT - 1; bit >= 0; --bit) // Print each byte
    std::cout << ((byte & (1 << bit)) == (1 << bit));
}
```

The above code will simply print each byte from the one at lower address to the one with higher address.

---

Edit: since it seems you're just interested in how many 1s and 0s are there (i.e. the order totally doesn't matter), in this specific instance I agree with the other answers and I would also just go for a counting solution

```
uint8_t *array = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&v);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i) {
  uint8_t byte = array[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; ++j) {
    std::cout << (byte & 0x1);
    byte >>= 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for this detailed response. To be honest, my main motivation here was to sum those ints, so that I could make a hash function going from doubles to size_t. In this sense, the order would not matter. However, I would be curious as to how you would do it if order did indeed matter.

Comment: @Learnaholic With that specific requirement (which would have made a lot of difference) I can only confirm that simply testing each bit is the right way to go (ignoring their order or internal representation). I can't help but notice that hashing might **not** be the best solution for floating point values. The reason being that comparing floating points for equality is tricky, so might be the result of hashing them. Even without bringing subnormals into play, hashing floating point values with a bit-by-bit test is still a bad idea due to potentially overlapping patterns.

Comment: As a follow-up comment I'd suggest taking a look at Boost. IIRC there's a floating point hashing module that you might take advantage of.

Comment: The comment about the overlapping patterns is absolutely true. I was however just using it for a toy tutorial example for myself. Thanks again!